mvn command under Ubuntu: the JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly. How is possible?
I have an issue opening an Eclipse project (Ubuntu 22.04 / OpenJDK 14 / Eclipse 4.31) :

Failed to execute mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0:enforce {execution: enforce-rules} (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0:enforce:enforce-rules:validate)

Then I tried to follow this thread.
I installed Maven 3.6:
sudo apt install maven

However, trying mvn -version command in terminal, I get:

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

So I checked $JAVA_HOME environment variable:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

Why should I need to modify the $JAVA_HOME variable for Maven at the risk every other Java dependent software may fail to work?
It could be really better to adapt Maven to read properly the $JAVA_HOME variable, but how?

Your JAVA_HOME is indeed mitsconfigured. It should point to the root of the JDK, i.e. usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64  instead of usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java.

No point installing an old Maven. Mine doesn't care that there's no JAVA_HOME

Thank you. However, JAVA_HOME variable is set by Ubuntu itself during installation and this is working for all other software I use. It is risky to change it on a production computer just to satisfy MAVEN.
Old one ? It was not installed by default. I just installed it from regular repositories. Which version do you suggest ?

if command line statement $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version is running (and showing a version) then the variable is correct, otherwise see first comment (the correct way) -- note that JAVA_HOME is not used by all applications, so "all other software" may still be working even if it is not set correctly

What does echo $JAVA_HOME actually say?

BTW if you do not want to change it globally, you can change it just to run one application (e.g. maven) -  on the command line, something like: JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64 mvn ... or was it export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64 ; mvn ...

fwiw, none of the Maven 3.6.x versions requires that JAVA_HOME be set

Yes user85421 ! This command: JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64 mvn -version is working! Thank you.
I prefer to not modify JAVA_HOME (I cannot easily check if everything else keeps working). echo $JAVA_HOME is preserved as I already show in the post. Thank you.

echo $JAVA_HOME is preserved as I already show in the post. OK, so if that's /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64/bin/java it's wrong. Better to see things that rely on something wrong fail than see (in certain circumstances) things that rely on something being correct fail

@g00se: I agree. Maybe this wrong JAVA_HOME setting should be reported to Ubuntu Canonical editor but I do not plan to enter this job just for what I need to do with MAVEN.

However, JAVA_HOME variable is set by Ubuntu itself during installation I assume you mean the installation of the JDK there? Whatever it is that you mean, I think the chances of that being the case are remote. Something/someone else has likely set JAVA_HOME (wrongly)

@life888888 this is not so much about where JDKs are, or which are active, but environment variables

That's a lot of words, life888888. I have re-read your first sentence several times, but still fail to find any meaning in it. As for the second sentence, that would be the case with any system, but as I said earlier, this is irrelevant to the problem in question, viz. of environment variables

How old is your Ubuntu? Consider upgrading.

Maybe one installed software modified JAVA_HOME (I did not check). I use Ubuntu 22.04, it is a bit early to upgrade to 24.04 for stability reason. Anyway, I succeeded to debug my code using Eclipse on a third party program. Thanks for your help.
